# How to test autocomplete using selenium and Python

Tags: python, django, selenium, autocomplete, selenium-webdriver

I've been writing a couple of tests using selenium for my website. However, I've not found a way to test an input textfield that is filled by auto completion. As an example, I want to select one of the locations that is displayed in an auto-complete list dropdown.

This is what I have so far:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("id_location_0").send_keys("Free City")
driver.find_element_by_id("ui-active-menuitem").click()
```

How is Auto-complete/Auto-suggest testing achieved in selenium using Python?

**NOTE:** Google search is a good example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean the auto-complete functionality of the web browser? Why would you want to test that? It's not part of your application, is it?  If it's about some AJAX call, then you need to wait until the menu is there. `time.sleep(...)` might be your friend between the two find_element_by_id lines.

Comment: This is not the auto-complete functionality of the browser. The auto-complete is part of the application. The values are fetched from the database.

Comment: When fetching from the database you definitely have to wait a bit before finding the element "ui-active-menuitem". Selenium is too fast, and fails to see the element because it is not loaded yet from the database. Give the time.sleep(1) a try, it should help.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the application but the general way to go is either:

Look at what type of elements are shown in the auto complete list, in the case of google it is  spans in a table, so you would do something like

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("css selector that matches all the auto complete suggestions)
```

then iterate through them until you find the one/ones you expect.

THe other option for google is to use the keydown events to select an option and the key enter to confirm that as your choice

Comment: Keydown doesn't seem to consistently work for me. Enter submits the page. Tab worked once on one field, but that was it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("id_location_0").send_keys("Free City")
element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.ui-autocomplete > :first-child ")
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
driver.find_element_by_id("ui-active-menuitem").click()
```

I'm sure this can be optimized in some way.

Comment: This is the code used in the current docs: `self.selenium.find_elements_by_css_selector('.yourlabs-autocomplete[data-input-id="id_fieldname-autocomplete"] [data-value]')` Didn't seem to work for me.. Only returned an empty list, but maybe it will help someone else.