# Django - Selecting Autocomplete-Light choices with Selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium, testing, autocomplete

I've been trying to figure out how to select an option from a drop-down created by [autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) for my tests.

The responses [here did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675138/how-to-test-autocomplete-using-selenium-and-python/20737463#comment56585070_20737463), and seem to be out of date.

I also tried an option from [autocomplete's code](http://pydoc.net/Python/django-autocomplete-light/2.0.5/autocomplete_light.tests.widget/).

I boiled down the code to this:
`self.selenium.find_elements_by_css_selector('.yourlabs-autocomplete[data-input-id="id_branch-autocomplete"][data-value]')`

where `id_branch-autocomplete` is the name of the field where data is being entered. However, it returned an empty list.

Has anyone been successful at this? I can't seem to find the element that appears in my browser's console and I don't understand CSS well enough to extrapolate the proper selector from the files.

Comment: can you share how this element looks on DOM level (html snippet or link to page) ?

Comment: Unfortunately the website is not live, and I'm too novice to pull the relevant code out of the autocomplete app itself. I'm looking for an example of it in the wild..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on this three times, before finally working this out.

Selenium needs to wait for the class named `hilight` to appear on the page. Only then should it attempt to click on it.

For this, I used the wait function I had gotten from one of my previous questions:
[Django: Selenium- stale element reference on browse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030816/django-selenium-stale-element-reference-on-browse)

I'll start with a simple one that worked for my first field, as it is less intimidating than my final solution.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def wait_for_element(self, elm, by = 'id', timeout=10):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, elm)))
    return self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(elm)

wait_for_element(self, "highlight", "class").click()
```

Where `driver` is the appropriate WebDriver that is being used to run the tests. The class is defined in `autocomplete.js` on line 245 in the version I am using:

`this.hilightClass = 'hilight';`

This, however, quickly proved to be ineffective, as forms with several autocomplete fields in a row would leave behind classes named `highlight`, thus confusing the webdriver. So I had to modify it use `xpath`, which made it a lot more powerful:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def wait_for_element(self, elm, by = 'id', timeout=10):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, elm)))
    return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(elm)
    wait_for_element(self,
                     "//span[@data-input-id='id_branch-autocomplete']/span[@data-value='1']",
                     "xpath").click()
```

`id_branch-autocomplete` should be replaced with whatever your field's `id` is, and the number value for `@data-value='x'` can be whichever option you'd like to select from the list that drops down. The first option is `1`, second is `2` and so on. Excellent!